# Can the financial details on the UK visitor visa application be different from the previous applications?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am going to start the visitor visa application process for my in-laws in India. My father-in-law has been to the UK once in 2014. My mother-in-law has been to the UK twice - once in 2014 and second time in 2015. They were both issued a visitor visa in 2017 on which they never travelled.

All of these times, my father-in-law's financial circumstances were different. He was employed full time so he was able to show stable income meeting his monthly expenses. This time though, he is going to be retiring next month without any pension. In the past, we never mentioned any of their properties or LIC policies etc. in the application as their financial circumstances looked solid even without those. But now, since he is going to be retired without any pension, I am inclined to include the details of all other savings and properties that he has.

Will the fact that he did not share information about his properties and savings in the previous applications be held against him this time?

Answer (score 1):

I can’t see why it would - it’s hardly realistic to include every single item of financial assets unless needed to demonstrate financial standing, and any individual’s financial circumstances may change over time. Being retired without a pension means he’s lost one avenue of demonstrating ties to home country and strong financial circumstances, but he has others that seem equally compelling. I would just include an explanation in the application and/or a covering letter.