# Financial circumstances for retired parents applying for UK visitor visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am going to start the visitor visa application process for my in-laws in India. My father-in-law has been to the UK once in 2014. My mother-in-law has been to the UK twice - once in 2014 and second time in 2015. They were both issued a visitor visa in 2017 on which they never travelled.

All of these times, my father-in-law's financial circumstances were different. He was employed full time so he was able to show stable income meeting his monthly expenses. This time though, he is going to be retiring next month without any pension from the employer. He does receive a tiny amount of pension (INR 2600 per month) from the provident fund. This has started very recently.

He has LIC policies that would mature in about a year's time. At the time of his retirement, he will receive his provident fund and gratuity which are very good sums of money.

I am going to be sponsoring their whole trip so they do not need to show any finances to support their trip. However, they will still need to provide evidence showing how they meet their ends. Are all the evidence I specified above enough in other's experience?

Comment: Preferable to include this in your previous question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112832/can-the-financial-details-on-the-uk-visitor-visa-application-be-different-from to provide the full picture and receive better answers

Comment: I was originally thinking to do that but then I thought it would be too many questions in a single question and a chance for someone who knows the answer to miss them in the detail.

Comment: Use a bullet point list for clarity

Comment: Could you clarify: are you saying he will receive his provident fund and gratuity in one year? You've said "at the time of retirement" which you've also said will be "next month".

Comment: Nope. His LIC policies which payout in about a year.  He retires in a month and a half. He will receive his provident fund and gratuity payments soon after that.

Answer (score 1):

If the timing of your parents’ visit isn’t critical, I’d postpone submitting the application until after your father’s retirement date when he will have received both the provident fund and gratuity you mention and will be able to provide evidence of this to show how he supports himself & family in India. The future maturity of LIC policies would then be the icing on the cake.

Comment: I considered that but timing is critical here. He can get a letter from his employer stating all those details but I am not sure how much weight will that carry.